# How to call Gradle task execution from outside task?

Tags: gradle

I have code:

```
task instalNodeModules { 
   doLast {
      npmInstall.execute()
      installGulp.execute()
   }
}

task runTasks {
   doLast {
      instalNodeModules.execute()
      gulpBuildWithOpts.execute()
   }
}
```

Gradle 4.5.1 warns about it as

> The TaskInternal.execute() method has been deprecated and is scheduled
>   to be removed in Gradle 5.0. There are better ways to re-use task
>   logic, see
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.5.1/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:reusing_task_logic.

But link does not give me any hint how I could replace it because I can’t just setup task dependencies like dependsOn or finalizdBy - it called not from other task but from end of build.

Comment: Why you can't set the dependencies up?

Comment: task instalNodeModules(dependsOn: ['npmInstall', 'installGulp']) like this?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You mustn't call `execute` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to call the `execute` method directly, but rather model your tasks dependencies. This allows gradle to perform up-to-date checks and only execute the tasks that are needed.

```
task runTasks {
   dependsOn installNodeModules
   dependsOn gulpBuildWithOpts
}
```